# Media Query для Samsung

Tags: media-queries, android, css

Здравствуйте.

Столкнулся с проблемой понимания стандартным андроидным браузером моих media query.

Тестил:

на Iphone4-5 - все ок;

на Samsung Note 2 - Crome - все ок;

на Samsung Note 2 - стандартный браузер - дикая каша;

на Samsung Galaxy S 2 - стандартный браузер - дикая каша.

Не могу понять, в чем прокол. Сейчас приведу код реализации Media Query, только сразу попрошу гнилыми помидорами в меня не бросать, потому как в работе с этими штуками я новичок. :)

```
@media screen and (max-width: 707px) {
    .moneyPackInfo {
        margin: 0px 9% 30px;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 690px) {
    .moneyPackInfo {
        margin: 0px 8% 30px;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 675px) {
    .moneyPackInfo {
        margin: 0px 7% 30px;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 660px) {
    .moneyPackInfo {
        margin: 0px 6% 30px;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 645px) {
    .moneyPackInfo {
        margin: 0px 5% 30px;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 630px) {
    .moneyPackInfo {
        margin: 0px 4% 30px;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 617px) {
    .moneyPackInfo {
        margin: 0px 3% 30px;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 604px) {
    .moneyPackInfo {
        margin: 0px 2% 30px;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 593px) {
    .moneyPackInfo {
        margin: 0px 1% 30px;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 581px) {
    .moneyPackInfo {
        margin: 0px 0% 30px;
    }
}
.........
@media screen and (max-width: 329px) {
.importantInfo span {
    left:25%;
    top:-48px;
    font-size:12px;
}
}
```

В `<head></head>` прописано:
`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`
`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />`
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1" />`
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />`

Помогите, плиз, разобраться с этой ситуевиной, а то ни один из вариантов, которые удалось нагуглить, не подошел. (

Спасибо.

Comment: А [такой вариант][1] пробовали?


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24074403/when-textbox-is-focused-css-media-stopped-working-on-mobilesamsung-galaxy-s4?rq=1

Comment: Ага, увы, но не работает (

Comment: Почитайте: http://hashcode.ru/questions/387823/html-медиа-запросы